# What are the './configure, make, make install' projects called?

Tags: linux, unix, autotools, autoconf, automake

I mean, those C or C++ projects that you build from source on Linux and UNIX systems, usually by issuing those commands:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

And they also have files like `./configure`, `./configure.ac`, `./configure.in` at the top directory.

I've heard them variously called autotools projects, or autoconf projects, or automake projects, but I'm not sure which name is the correct one. Is there even a consensus on what they should be called?

Comment: Beware: configure.in is deprecated. Its replacement is configure.ac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autoconf and automake are collectively called the GNU autotools (and libtool may be included in that category as well), so autotools is the most general name.

Note that not all programs that have a `configure` script to generate a makefile are necessarily using the autotools, or not all of them.

Comment: So we would call such a project "an autotools project"?

Comment: Just want to point out that it isn't necessary that the sequence of commands mentioned by the OP use any of the autotools at all. The [GNU Coding Standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Configuration.html) itself makes this quite clear. The wording suggests that one could even write a `configure' script by hand, as long as it behaves the intended way, implements a certain interface (arguments) and enforces certain things (like the impossibility of building without having configured first, etc).

Comment: @ArjunShankar: that's a really good point. Added an example of that to the answer.

Comment: `git` uses autoconf to generate the configure script, but uses a hand-written Makefile.  (It does not use automake).

Answer (score 4):

According to GNU it's officially called the [GNU Build System](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/GNU-Build-System.html), which is where you find it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system).  But most people (er, almost everyone?) calls it "the GNU autotools" or "autotools".  As stated by @larsmans and others in his answer, *none* of these tools are required.  To quote the last paragraph of the link:

> The Autotools are tools that will create a GNU Build System for your package. Autoconf mostly focuses on configure and Automake on Makefiles. It is entirely possible to create a GNU Build System without the help of these tools....

Answer (score 0):

The first page of the autoconf info page refers to the packages as "autoconfiscated".